# JavaScript image at onload event

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am trying to load a new image every time the previously loaded image has finished loading.
The function `create_photo_list` works correctly. It creates an array of the photos that need to be loaded. If none need to be loaded then the array is empty. The problem is, when there are no more items to load the it keeps calling the `load_next_photo` function.

The reason I call the `registerEventHandler` every time in the function is because if I don't, the function is not called when the next photo loads.

```
    function registerEventHandler(node, event, handler) {
    if (typeof node.addEventListener == "function")
        node.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    else
        node.attachEvent("on" + event, handler);
}

// Remove an HTML element event handler such as onclick
// ex: unregisterEventHandler($("textfield"), "keypress", showEvent);
function unregisterEventHandler(node, event, handler) {
if (typeof node.removeEventListener == "function")
    node.removeEventListener(event, handler, false);
else
    node.detachEvent("on" + event, handler);
}

function load_next_photo() {
    var loading_list = create_photo_list();
    alert(loading_list.length);
    if (loading_list.length > 0) {
        img[loading_list[0]]['loaded'] = 1;
        registerEventHandler($("load_img"), "onload", load_next_photo());
        $("load_img").src = img[loading_list[0]]['img'];
    }
    else {
        alert("nothing");
        unregisterEventHandler($("load_img"), "onload", load_next_photo())
    }
    unregisterEventHandler($("load_img"), "onload", load_next_photo())
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using jquery for all your event listening code?

Comment: I'm an amateur developer and I haven't heard of it before ;)
I would really prefer an answer to a workaround though.

Comment: no no, I meant all the `$("load_img")` calls. That looks like jquery (unless you have your own framework setup).

Comment: I would remove the () from load_next_photo here:  `..registerEventHandler($("load_img"), "onload", load_next_photo());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't get my head around what you currently have, but such code works just fine:

```
var _images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];
var _index = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    LoadImage();
};

function LoadImage() {
    //stop condition:
    if (_index >= _images.length)
        return false;

    var url = _images[_index];
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() {
        _index++;
        LoadImage();
    };

    document.getElementById("Container").appendChild(img);
}
```

This will add the images to the container (element with ID `Container`) one by one, live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/vkQQ7/

This is plain JS, feel free to ask about any part for elaboration. :)

Comment: Version with alerts to show it's really loading one after the other: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/vkQQ7/1/

Comment: So it works, but I have an array outside of the function called img. When I try to reference it in the function (for example alert(img[first_photo]['img']);) it gives an uncaught type error: cannot read property '3' of undefined. I _know_ that the array exists. What would be causing this?

Comment: @Sam try `alert(typeof img);` - what you see? If "undefined" it means that for some reason it's **not** defined anywhere. Post relevant code (in edit of your original question) and we'll try to see why. Please post comment when you do this so I get notified.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard It is "undefined". The img array is actually created using php, so it is easier if you just view the source of the [page](http://goo.gl/KazNv).

Comment: @Sam - mystery solved.. I also call my local variable `img` thus it "overrides" the global variable. Change the code in my function to: `var image = new Image(); image.src = url; image.onload = ...` and it should work.

Comment: @Sam took me too long to figure that variable conflict, just today I learned that the local variables inside a function are "pre compiled", so the overwriting happens in the very first line. So, thank you! :)