# How do i make a function so that the programming line will wait until it's done and move to the next line in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML5 with Javascript,
but sometimes the code is executing the next line of statement
before the current line is finished,

For example,
I'm passing an image to an object in Javascript,
but then the next statement is executed already before the object has the image,
so sometimes the object has no image, but sometimes it has,

So between the 2 lines I need to assign something like callback or wait function,
but i dont know how

```
var image=new Image();
ws.send("complete");
```

Comment: Sometimes the image is not initiated and that cause an error, but sometimes it will be displayed (depends on the browser and memory), because I also use websocket

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is (mostly) asynchronous, which is a good thing. You dont want to block the UI while waiting on an image for example.

Use the following to execute ws.send after the images has completed:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function()
{
 ws.send("complete");
}
image.src = 'image.jpg';
```

If you would do this synchronous the whole program would block, and you dont want that.

As for callbacks, you can just pass a function as an argument to your function. For example:

```
function doSomething(callback)
{       
    callback();
}

doSomething(function()
{
 console.log('im done!');
});
```

Comment: I was too slow :-) 
but remember, for this to work in IE, the `onload` event needs to be assigned before the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question is image specific, but for images, you can do the following:
The onload event will fire once the image is loaded.

```js
var im = new Image();
im.onload = function() { ws.send('complete'); }
im.src = 'path/to/image.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: [Javascript image onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366967/javascript-image-onload#5368113)

essentially you have to write an eventlistener that catches the event when the image is loaded.